# add table to pdo mock object

Tags: php, unit-testing, pdo

i have been following a tutorial to create pdo mock object. i used `var_dump` to understand what this pdo mock contains and i find the structure very confusing. what i want to do it's to query a table named 'providers' which should contain the data from the `dataProvider` method. 
this is the pdo creation:

```
class AdProvidersTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function dataProvider()
    {
        return array (
            array (1, '1st', 'desc_1', 11),
            array (2, '2nd', 'desc_2', 22),
            array (3, '3rd', 'desc_3', 33),
        );
    }
    /**
     * @dataProvider dataProvider
     */
    public function testAdProviders($id, $name, $desc, $account_id)
    {
        $data = array (
            array (
                'id' => $id,
                'name' => $name,
                'description' => $desc,
                'account_id' => $account_id
            )
        );

        $stmt = $this->getMock('PDOStatement', array ('fetchAll'));
        $stmt->expects($this->any())
             ->method('fetchAll')
             ->will($this->returnValue($data));

        $pdo = $this->getMock('PDO', array('prepare'),
            array('sqlite:dbname=:memory'),'PDOMock_' . uniqid(),true);
        $pdo->expects($this->any())
            ->method('prepare')
            ->will($this->returnValue($stmt));


        var_dump($pdo);
    }

}
```

how can i create a table named 'providers' inside the mock object, so when i query it like this for example `SELECT * FROM providers`, i will get this three lines from the dataProvider?

the function i actually want to test:

```
  function getProviders() {
    if ($this->providers == null){
      $DBH = $this->getDbh();
      $query = "select * from providers";
      $STH = $DBH->query($query);
      $STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
      while($provider = $STH->fetch()) {
        $this->providers[$provider['id']] = $provider;
      }
    }
    return $this->providers;
  }
```